# Method Illuminate\\\\Support\\\\Collection::latest does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to append a last_messages accessor to my Chat model forappending last 10 messages, however I'm getting this error:

> Method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::latest does not exist.

My accessor code, which I append using $appends

```
protected $appends = ['has_unread','last_messages'];

public function getLastMessagesAttribute()
    {
        //return collect($this->messages)->latest('created_at')->first();
        return collect($this->messages)->latest('created_at')->take(10)->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a `one-to-many` relation so you could do that like this by removing the `collect` method

```php
public function getLastMessagesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->messages()->latest('created_at')->take(10)->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`latest()` is an **Eloquent** method for queries that essentially asks the database to `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`.

Unfortunately, this method does not exist on the Laravel **collection** (thus the error message).

You can, however, make this work the way you want, using a different method on your collection.

Try:

```
return collect($this->messages)->sortBy('created_at');
```

You can get pretty crafty with `sortBy`, creating virtually anything you want using a closure:

```
$x = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
    return count($product['colors']);
});
```

The base method also takes a variety of standard PHP sort flags to make life easy.  E.g.:

```
$collection->sortBy('title', SORT_NATURAL);
```

Check [the Laravel docs on this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby) for a little more detail.